# Program seems to silently terminate after for-loop - C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, recursion, execution

I have created a program that prints out all of the permutations of the characters provided through command-line arguments and decided I wanted to compare execution time to an equivalent program written in Java.

The program worked until I decided to find the permutations multiple times in order to get an average execution time.

```
void avgTime(char**& argv, int times) {
    if (sizeof(argv) > 1) {

        long permutationAmnt;

        clock_t s_start, s_end, t_start, t_end;
        float s_runms, t_runms;

        long avg_time;

        for (int count = 0; count < times; count++) {

            t_start = clock();

            for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(argv); i++) {
                s_start = clock();
                permutationAmnt = permutations(std::string(argv[i]));
                s_end = clock();

                s_runms = ((float)s_end - s_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
                std::cout << "SUCCESS (" << s_runms << "ms for " << permutationAmnt << " permutations)" << std::endl << std::endl;
            }

            t_end = clock();

            t_runms = ((float) t_end - t_start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000;
            std::cout << std::endl << "TOTAL RUNTIME: " << t_runms << "ms" << std::endl;
            avg_time += t_runms;
        }

        std::cout << "AVERAGE RUNTIME: " << avg_time / times << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    avgTime(argv, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The first for-loop in `avgTime()` only executes a single time (putting a cout inside of it only prints one time) and the program appears to terminate after the nested for-loop breaks.

I am not sure if the problem is with some of the code from `avgTime()` or if it comes from one of the helper functions, like `permute()`. Either way here is the code for each of the helper functions as well as the includes (p.s. `num` is declared outside of any functions).

```
/*
* Calls the recursive permute() function then
* returns the total amount of permutations possible
* for the given input.
*
* NOTE: the num variable is used in the permute() function
* for numbering the permutations printed as output (see next function
* for clarificiation)
*/
long permutations(const std::string& arg) {
    long totalPermutations = factorial(arg.size()); //self-explanatory

    num = 1;
    permute(arg, 0);

    return totalPermutations;
}


/*
 * Recursively prints out each permutation
 * of the characters in the argument, str
 */
void permute(const std::string& str, int place) {
    if (place == str.size() - 1) std::cout << ((num <= 10) ? "0" : "") << num++ << ". " << str << std::endl;

    for (int i = place; i < str.size(); i++) {
        permute(swap(place, i, str), place + 1); //self-explanatory
    }
}

long factorial(int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return factorial(num - 1) * num;
}

std::string swap(int i, int j, const std::string& str) {
    std::string s(str);
    s[i] = s[j];
    s[j] = str[i];
    return s;
}
```

NOTE: the `permute()` function appears before the `permutation()` function in the source code and is visible to all the necessary callers of it.

```
//Includes and namespace stuff
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
```

I would appreciate any help that you guys can offer, if there is any additional information that you would like me to provide just let me know. Thanks again for any help.

P.S. No, this isn't a homework assignment :P

EDIT: Removed `using namespace std;` and adjusted the code accordingly to avoid confusion between the function `std::swap()` and my own `swap()` function. Also, added the `swap()` and `factorial()` functions to avoid any ambiguity. I apologize for the confusion this caused.

Comment: `//Self-explanatory` - I love comments like this

Comment: std::cout just about makes any performance test meaningless.And you should avoid `using namespace std;`

Comment: Hi @George, I made the edit so it is clearer.

Comment: @lakeweb Yeah, I realize now that `std::cout` would make really any of my results worthless. Nonetheless, I'm still interested in what is causing the problem. Also, about the `using namespace`, what is the reason for avoiding it? I never use `namespace std` in any header files because I know that it will leak into any other file that `#include`s it. Is there more to why it should be avoided though? I'll stop doing it, I'm just curious about if there are any more harmful side-effects of doing it.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(argv); i++) {` does not do what you want.  The argc argument to main tells you how many parameters were passed on the command line and stored in argv. Use that. This would also be a good time to learn to use a debugger so you can see where your program fails. As far as your example goes, it would be much better to strip out all of the verbose comments that are unnecessary to the example, put it all in one file, and post it all in one code block. Since you didn't include `factorial()` you program can't be tested by others.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for the fix! I'm not sure why I didn't just use `argc` from the beginning. I'll certainly start learning how to use debuggers, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yea, I wish I could test it. How did you get it to compile using std::swap like that? And if you have your own swap, a perfect example of not `using namespace std;`. It cuts down on the confusion of when you use the standard. Even with a dozen lines I'll std::function.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Me too, especially for the 3 argument swap, and of course `using namespace std` makes it impossible to know if it's supposed to use `std::swap and is an error, or if the strange function is just missing.

Comment: Sorry for all of the confusion around the `swap()` function. I've modified the question so that it is no longer ambiguous about which `swap()` function is being called (mine vs. standard library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `sizeof(argv)` rather than just using `argc`. Switching to the latter option fixed the issue.

Comment: To wit. std::cout will probably use way more resources than your code and will be unpredictable. The console output for Java may be entirely different. Timing on a machine where the OS is sharing processor resources with services and other apps will also skew thing badly. You can't use your own clock. Use a development tool with diagnostics for timing.

Comment: @lakeweb Thank you for all of your input. I will no longer use this program for any meaningful data analysis and will only consider it to be for learning purposes. I will keep your suggestions in mind for any future applications that I create.